# Как добавить текст в таблице перед полем Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, текст, table, entry

Как добавить текст в таблице перед полем Entry в Python Tk?

```
import tkinter as tk
```

from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle, random

class MyEntry(tk.Entry):

```
def __init__(self, master,  x, y, number,*args, **kwargs):
    super(MyEntry, self).__init__(master, font = 'Calibri 15 bold' ,*args, **kwargs)
    self.x = x 
    self.y = y
    self.number = number
   
def __repr__(self):
    return f'MyEntry{self.x} {self.y} {self.number}'
```

class MineSweeper:

```
window = Tk()
ROW = 6
COLUMNS = 4
MINES = 24


def __init__(self):
    self.entry = []
    count = 1
    
    for i in range(MineSweeper.ROW):
        temp = []
        for j in range(MineSweeper.COLUMNS):
           ent = MyEntry(MineSweeper.window,x=i, y=j,  number=count)      
           temp.append(ent)
           count +=1
        self.entry.append(temp)

def create_widget(self):
    for i in range(MineSweeper.ROW):
        for j in range(MineSweeper.COLUMNS):
            ent = self.entry[i][j]
            ent.grid(row =i, column= j)



def start(self):
    self.create_widget()
    self.print_entry()

    MineSweeper.window.mainloop()

def print_entry(self):
    for row_entry in self.entry:
        print(row_entry)
```

game = MineSweeper()
game.start()

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите проблему более подробно. Что у вас не получается? Что вы пробовали? Рекомендую прочитать статью [ask] и отредактировать вопрос кнопкой [edit].

Answer (score 0):

у меня есть код и мне надо чтобы перед полем был текст

class MyEntry(tk.Entry):

```
def __init__(self, master,  x, y, number,*args, **kwargs):
    super(MyEntry, self).__init__(master, font = 'Calibri 15 bold' ,*args, **kwargs)
    self.x = x 
    self.y = y
    self.number = number
   
def __repr__(self):
    return f'MyEntry{self.x} {self.y} {self.number}'
```

class MineSweeper:

```
window = Tk()
ROW = 6
COLUMNS = 4
MINES = 24


def __init__(self):
    self.entry = []
    count = 1
    
    for i in range(MineSweeper.ROW):
        temp = []
        for j in range(MineSweeper.COLUMNS):
           ent = MyEntry(MineSweeper.window,x=i, y=j,  number=count)      
           temp.append(ent)
           count +=1
        self.entry.append(temp)

def create_widget(self):
    for i in range(MineSweeper.ROW):
        for j in range(MineSweeper.COLUMNS):
            ent = self.entry[i][j]
            ent.grid(row =i, column= j)



def start(self):
    self.create_widget()
    self.print_entry()

    MineSweeper.window.mainloop()

def print_entry(self):
    for row_entry in self.entry:
        print(row_entry)
```

game = MineSweeper()
game.start()

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите